# Telnet localhost access for root user

Tags: command-line, server, root, telnet

I have installed telnet in my Ubuntu 14.04 PC. I am able to telnet a remote machine in same network. But I cannot telnet to my PC with root user which is local host.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: You installed the client, but did you install a server?

Comment: Hi Ziazis, No, I tried google search but it didn't help to install server.

Comment: You have probably installed the package "telnet" so if you want to use it on your host install also "telnet-server". However why not use ssh instead of that?

Comment: I already have ssh. But telnet server is needed for my selenium framework. So i need telnet server Ziazis. Let me try with sudo apt-get install telnet-server.

Comment: Telnet is not considdered safe theese days, since it sends usaernames and passwords (and every thing else) in clear text on the network. Use ssh instead.

Comment: Ok i will update it but whats the installation procedure for telnet server?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install telnet-server`. It will respond that `telnet-server` is a virtual package provided by a number of real packages. Pick one; it doesn't really matter which one.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. After your step. But it didn't enable for root login. Is there anything i need to enable for root telnet server access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration let me to telnet localhost.

# Simple configuration file for xinetd
    #
    # Some defaults, and include /etc/xinetd.d/

```
service telnet
{
disable = no
flags = REUSE
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
log_on_failure += USERID
}

defaults
{

# Please note that you need a log_type line to be able to use log_on_success
# and log_on_failure. The default is the following :
# log_type = SYSLOG daemon info
# Please note that you need a log_type line to be able to use log_on_success
# and log_on_failure. The default is the following :
# log_type = SYSLOG daemon info
instances = 60
log_type = SYSLOG authpriv
log_on_success = HOST PID
log_on_failure = HOST
cps = 25 30
}

includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```